# where styles from QGIS are saved in PostgreSQl

Tags: qgis, postgresql, style

I can save style of a layer in DB PostgreSQL.
[image]

But where is it stored in Postgres? How can I find it?

Comment: I am too curious to know about ... is there any provision to save styles in postgresql/postgis db.

Comment: I'll found it. It is saved in the table layer styles which is created automatically.

Comment: @bable, Since you answered your own question, please provide an "Answer" below and then mark it as accepted.  If you could also add a bit more detail about what you found, such as which table you found the styles saved in, and what format it was saved, and any other additional information that would be helpful to future readers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Style of the QGIS layer is saved in the DB in the table 'layer styles' which is created automatically.
layer styles includes information about style (color, labels and other), form (if it was created in QGIS ) described using XML.

```
select * from public.layer_styles
```

[image]